# Pyspark Aggregation of an array of structs

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate-functions

I have the following schema in pyspark:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- data: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- seconds: decimal(38,18) (nullable = true)
 |-- total_seconds: decimal(38,3) (nullable = true)
```

I have two pyspark dataframes which I need to join and aggregate together. Each data frame has the same schema.

Given the following input in one data frame:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "data": [{
        "id": "123",
        "name": "name1",
        "seconds": 50
    }, {
        "id": "234",
        "name": "name2",
        "seconds": 25
    }],
    "total_seconds": 100
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "data": [{
        "id": "123",
        "name": "name1",
        "seconds": 100
    }, {
        "id": "234",
        "name": "name2",
        "seconds": 200
    }],
    "total_seconds": 400
}]
```

In the second dataframe I have the following data:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "data": [{
        "id": "123",
        "name": "name1",
        "seconds": 100
    }, {
        "id": "345",
        "name": "name3",
        "seconds": 25
    }],
    "total_seconds": 400
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "data": [{
        "id": "123",
        "name": "name1",
        "seconds": 50
    }, {
        "id": "234",
        "name": "name2",
        "seconds": 100
    }],
    "total_seconds": 200
}]
```

I would then expect this output:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "data": [{
        "id": "123",
        "name": "name1",
        "seconds": 150
    }, {
        "id": "234",
        "name": "name2",
        "seconds": 25
    }, {
        "id": "345",
        "name": "name3",
        "seconds": 25
    }],
    "total_seconds": 500
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "data": [{
        "id": "123",
        "name": "name1",
        "seconds": 100
    }, {
        "id": "234",
        "name": "name2",
        "seconds": 200
    }],
    "total_seconds": 400
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "data": [{
        "id": "123",
        "name": "name1",
        "seconds": 50
    }, {
        "id": "234",
        "name": "name2",
        "seconds": 100
    }],
    "total_seconds": 200
}]
```

Essentially, I need to do the following:

1. Join on the id column
2. Aggregate the total_seconds
3. Aggregate / merge the data column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by joining the 2 dataframes, explode() and groupBy() will help also to manipulate the data before and after the join, here's the tested code, you can add shows between the transformations if something is nor clear, or leave a comment below:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
df1 = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json("json1.json")
df2 = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json("json2.json") \
    .withColumnRenamed("data", "data_2").withColumnRenamed("id", "id_2").withColumnRenamed("total_seconds", "total_seconds_2")

df1_exploded = df1.withColumn("data", explode(col("data")))
df2_exploded = df2.withColumn("data_2", explode(col("data_2"))).drop("total_seconds_2")

resultDf = df1_exploded.join(df2_exploded, (df1_exploded.id == df2_exploded.id_2) & (
            df1_exploded.data.id == df2_exploded.data_2.id), "outer") \
    .withColumn("id", coalesce(col("id"), col("id_2"))) \
    .withColumn("data",
                struct(coalesce(col("data.id"), col("data_2.id")), coalesce(col("data.name"), col("data_2.name")),
                       coalesce(col("data.seconds"), lit(0)) + coalesce(col("data_2.seconds"), lit(0)))) \
    .select("data", "id", "total_seconds") \
    .groupby("id").agg(collect_list("data").alias("data"))

total_seconds_df = df1.join(df2, df1.id == df2.id_2, "outer")\
    .withColumn("id", coalesce(col("id"), col("id_2")))\
    .withColumn("total_seconds", coalesce(col("total_seconds"), lit(0)) + coalesce(col("total_seconds_2"), lit(0)))\
    .select("id", "total_seconds")
resultDf = resultDf.join(total_seconds_df, ["id"], "left")
resultDf.show()
```

Result:

```
+---+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
|id |data                                                   |total_seconds|
+---+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
|1  |[{123, name1, 150}, {234, name2, 25}, {345, name3, 25}]|500          |
|3  |[{123, name1, 50}, {234, name2, 100}]                  |200          |
|2  |[{123, name1, 100}, {234, name2, 200}]                 |400          |
+---+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I had kept trying to do it in a single chain, but separating those two distinct operations simplified things.

Only change I needed to make was to alias the struct creation to their proper names!